# div with absolute position colliding

Tags: javascript, css, pdf.js

I have a requirement of annotating a pdf file.I have used pdf.js and for highlighting the selected text I have used the code given in https://gist.github.com/yurydelendik/f2b846dae7cb29c86d23 .
 The code creates div for each selected div with background color and top left value.The divs are positioned absolute.The snapshot of highlighted text in pdf is as follows:-[image: highligted text in pdf]

each row is the combination of div or a single div with top left and height and width value

```
<div class="highlight"  style="position: absolute; border:none; background-color:#ffff99;opacity: 0.5;left:1735.8398844401042px; top:2601.3912037037035px;width:1007.511284722222px; height:49.333333333333485px;"></div>
```

You can clearly see that each div has collided with another.Is there any way to omit the collision or any means to remove the dark underline created due to div collision.The div has to be positioned absolute as the top left value is saved in backend.The collision varies in browser and zoom level of pdf in pdf.js

Comment: Remove the background-color and opacity rules from the style attribute on all the divs. Should look better.

Comment: If I remove the opacity and background then there is no use of using this feature

Comment: Try giving line-height of 10px.

Comment: using line-height does help but the value for line-height is dynamic and unpredictable for each div @SujataChanda .ny thnx

Comment: Then try with margin-bottom or padding-bottom also.

Comment: It's weird but Firefox and Chrome return different values in getBoundingClientRect

Comment: @async5 yes it's been a headache for me

Comment: Did you try setting `line-height: 1`? See also https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6614 (marked as easy bug)

Comment: @async5 I tried that already as SujataChanda mentioned that already.The problem with https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6614 was that he was using bootstrap with line-height more than one. I tried a very different approach from javascript which solved my problem .Thank you for your concern and help.